# Contar valores em múltiplas tabelas relacionadas

Tags: sql, query, join, microsoft-access, count

Tenho 4 tabelas `tbl_Distrito`, `tbl_Unidade`, `tbl_Servidor`, `tbl_Processo`.

```
tbl_Distrito: Cod_Distrito, Nome_Distrito

tbl_Unidade: Cod_Unidade, Nome_Unidade, Cod_Distrito

tbl_Servidor: Cod_Unidade

tbl_Processo: Cod_Unidade
```

Basicamente eu preciso listar todas as unidade e contar quantas vezes cada unidade aparece na tabela Servidor e na tabela Processo pra conseguir comparar esses valores:

Minha consulta:

```
SELECT DISTRITO.NOME_DISTRITO,
       UNIDADE.NOME_UNIDADE,
       COUNT(SERVIDOR.UNIDADE_COD_UNIDADE) AS CONTAGEM_1,
       COUNT(PROCESSO_HAS_UNIDADE.UNIDADE_COD_UNIDADE_SOLICITADA) AS CONTAGEM_2
  FROM (DISTRITO INNER
        JOIN(UNIDADE INNER JOIN PROCESSO_HAS_UNIDADE ON
             UNIDADE.COD_UNIDADE =
             PROCESSO_HAS_UNIDADE.UNIDADE_COD_UNIDADE_SOLICITADA) ON
        DISTRITO.COD_DISTRITO = UNIDADE.DISTRITO_COD_DISTRITO)
 INNER JOIN SERVIDOR
    ON UNIDADE.COD_UNIDADE = SERVIDOR.UNIDADE_COD_UNIDADE
 GROUP BY DISTRITO.NOME_DISTRITO, UNIDADE.NOME_UNIDADE;
```

O problema é que minha consulta está retornando valores iguais para `CONTAGEM_1` e `CONTAGEM_2`.

[image: Conforme segue a imagem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, segue a solução para os próximos aventureiros:

```
SELECT DISTRITO.NOME_DISTRITO, DERIVADA.NOME_UNIDADE, DERIVADA.TOTAL_PROCESSO, Count(SERVIDOR.UNIDADE_COD_UNIDADE) AS TOTAL_SERVIDOR
FROM DISTRITO 
INNER JOIN ((SELECT UNIDADE.DISTRITO_COD_DISTRITO, UNIDADE.COD_UNIDADE, UNIDADE.NOME_UNIDADE, COUNT(PROCESSO.UNIDADE_COD_UNIDADE) AS TOTAL_PROCESSO
FROM UNIDADE
LEFT JOIN PROCESSO
ON PROCESSO.UNIDADE_COD_UNIDADE = UNIDADE.COD_UNIDADE
GROUP BY UNIDADE.DISTRITO_COD_DISTRITO, UNIDADE.COD_UNIDADE, UNIDADE.NOME_UNIDADE) AS DERIVADA 
LEFT JOIN SERVIDOR 
ON DERIVADA.COD_UNIDADE = SERVIDOR.UNIDADE_COD_UNIDADE) 
ON DISTRITO.COD_DISTRITO = DERIVADA.DISTRITO_COD_DISTRITO
GROUP BY DISTRITO.NOME_DISTRITO, DERIVADA.NOME_UNIDADE, DERIVADA.TOTAL_PROCESSO, DERIVADA.DISTRITO_COD_DISTRITO, DERIVADA.COD_UNIDADE
HAVING (((DERIVADA.TOTAL_PROCESSO)<>0) OR ((Count(SERVIDOR.UNIDADE_COD_UNIDADE))<>0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Oi,

Acredito que você possa combinar um LEFT JOIN entre tbl_Unidade e tbl_Servidor e entre tbl_Unidade e tbl_Processo

Ficaria assim

```
select  UNIDADE.Nome_Unidade,
        DISTRITO.Nome_Distrito,
        COUNT(SERVIDOR.Cod_Unidade) AS CONTAGEM_1,
        COUNT(PROCESSO.Cod_Unidade) AS CONTAGEM_2
from    tbl_Unidade UNIDADE
left    join tbl_Servidor SERVIDOR on UNIDADE.Cod_Unidade = SERVIDOR.Cod_Unidade
left    join tbl_Processo PROCESSO on UNIDADE.Cod_Unidade = PROCESSO.Cod_Unidade
join    tbl_Distrito DISTRITO on UNIDADE.Cod_Distrito = DISTRITO..Cod_Distrito
GROUP   by UNIDADE.Nome_Unidade, DISTRITO.Nome_Distrito;
```

Comment: A ideia foi boa mas também não funcionou, continuou a repetir os valores nas duas colunas de contagem. Acredito que preciso de uma subconsulta.

Comment: Tenta fazer de duas em duas tabelas, depois você junta os joins, o Left join deve trazer mesmo que não encontre a chave extrangeira